# Password protect directory on IIS 7

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis-7, .htpasswd

I run my site on IIS 7 in godaddy. I need to create a password protected directory.

How can I get that in IIS? In apache, it uses .htaccess and .htpasswd.

I need to replicate .htpasswd's functionality on IIS. What alternative can be used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871) has step by step instructions for adding authentication to a folder using the web.config file. It's a little more complicated in IIS than creating a password file.